# UIWebView disable highlight when the user clink on a link tag a

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Is it possible to remove the gray highlight when the user click on a link? I tried with css but it doesn't work.

Comment: So, didn't `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a great solution that makes the alpha transparent

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with UIWebView UIKit Control in iOS. The customization of that control is very very marginal. UIWebView shouldn't be subclassed either.

Under [Subclassing Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2) of the `UIWebView` reference, all it says is:

> #### Subclassing Notes
>
> The UIWebView class should not be subclassed.

Apple is very protective of this UI element.